# Spring Controller: Validation failed for object='invoiceData'. Error count: 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, thymeleaf

I have two objects, `Contractor`, with a field `ContractorData`, and the `ContractorData` has a list of objects of type `Invoice`:

```
Contractor
    id
    email
    ContractorData

ContractorData
    id
    FistName
    LastName
    ...
    List<InvoiceData>
```

For the Contractor update, I have a basic controller

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    String email = String.valueOf(((LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) authentication.getUserAuthentication().getDetails()).get("email"));
    Contractor contractor = contractorRepository.findByEmail(email);
    if (contractor == null) {
        contractor = new Contractor();
        contractor.setEmail(email);
        contractorRepository.save(contractor);
    }
    model.addAttribute("contractor", contractor);
    return "index";
}
```

and an update controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contractor/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
        public String updateContractor(@PathVariable("id") String id, Contractor contractor, Model model) {
        Contractor contractorPO = contractorRepository.findById(id).get();
        ContractorData contractorData = ContractorData.builder()
                .firstName(contractor.getContractorData().getFirstName())
                .lastName(contractor.getContractorData().getLastName())
                .businessName(contractor.getContractorData().getBusinessName())
                .businessLocation(contractor.getContractorData().getBusinessLocation())
                .nip(contractor.getContractorData().getNip())
                .regon(contractor.getContractorData().getRegon())
                .build();
        contractorPO.setContractorData(contractorData);
        contractorRepository.save(contractorPO);
        model.addAttribute("contractor", contractorPO);
        return "index";
    }
```

Here everything works perfectly.

But then, I have a controller leading to a page on which one can add a `InvoiceData`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{id}")
public String addPage(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model) {
    InvoiceData invoiceData = new InvoiceData();
    model.addAttribute("contractorid", id);
    model.addAttribute("invoicedata", invoiceData);
    return "add";
}
```

And a controller for adding invoice:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/addinvoice/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public String addInvoice(@PathVariable("id") String id, InvoiceData data, Model model) {
        Contractor contractor = contractorRepository.findById(id).get();
        contractor.getInvoices().add(data);
        contractorRepository.save(contractor);
        model.addAttribute("contractor", contractor);
        return "index";
    }
```

On the HTML forms side the form for index.html looks like this:

```
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/contractor/update/{id}(id=${contractor.id})}" th:object="${contractor}" method="post">
            <ul class="form-style-1">
                <li>
                    <label>First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{contractorData.firstName}" id="firstName" th:value="${contractor.contractorData?.firstName}">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Last Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{contractorData.lastName}" id="lastName" th:value="${contractor.contractorData?.lastName}">
                </li>
                ... and more
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Form for the `add.html` looks the same, it differs in the object:

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{addinvoice/{id}(id=${contractorid})}" th:object="${invoicedata}" method="post">
        <ul class="form-style-1">
            <li>
                <label>Reception date<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="date" th:field="*{receptionDate}" id="receptionDate">
            </li>
            ... and more
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

The problem is with saving the `InvoiceData`. When I fill out the form, and click Submit - I receive an error:

There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='invoiceData'. Error count: 4

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

On the console output I also get an error:

```
Field error in object 'invoiceData' on field 'contractDate': rejected value [2019-04-11]; codes [typeMismatch.invoiceData.contractDate,typeMismatch.contractDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [invoiceData.contractDate,contractDate]; arguments []; default message [contractDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'contractDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Date] for value '2019-04-11'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

But as I said before, EVERYTHING goes fine with `ContractorData` update form...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is java.date.
because in html the date is in format 'yyyy-MM-dd'. you are getting error because 
spring could not convert this date to java.Date.

you might have declared receptionDate  like this

```
Date receptionDate;
```

now, change to

```
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
     Date receptionDate;
```